# how can i run rouge Summarization on windows?

Tags: windows, perl

I installed Strawberry Perl to run the `rouge` program in Windows. But when I want to run my program, I receive an error message that you can see on the image:

```
The system can't find the path  specified.
```

My code is attempting to run "ROUGE-1.5.5.pl" but i think the system can't find this file.  So I think maybe I don't initialize the path correctly?

I change my code to :

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
  use Cwd;
  $curdir=getcwd;
  $ROUGE="..\ROUGE-1.5.5.pl";
  chdir("sample-test");
  $cmd="$ROUGE -e ..\data -c 95 -2 -1 -U -r 1000 -n 4 -w 1.2 -a DUC2002-ROUGE.in.26.spl.xml > ..\sample-output\output.out";
  print $cmd,"\n";
  system($cmd);
  chdir($curdir);
```

and i receive this error:
Missing braces on \o{} at C:\runROUGE-test.pl line 7, near "$ROUGE" Execution of C:\runROUGE-test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP9Ef.png]

Comment: A copy/paste of the relevant code and the error message would be worlds better than an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the screen shot, you are attempting to run `\ROUGE-1.5.5.pl` where you probably want it without the spurious backslash (or with `..\ROUGE-1.5.5.pl` if the parent directory is not on your `PATH`).

Similarly, you probably want the output in `sample-output\output.out`, or even just `output.out`, not `\sample-output\output.out` unless you specifically have a folder `C:\sample-output` for this purpose.

The backslash is significant; it is the absolute path to the root (of the current drive, on Windows). `..\` is the relative path to the parent folder.

Why are you writing a Perl script to run a Perl script, though?  Either a simple batch file, or copy/pasting the command directly at the DOS prompt would seem like a less roundabout solution.

Comment: i change my backslash but now i got this error:
Missing braces on \o{} at C:\runROUGE-test.pl line 7, near "$ROUGE"
Execution of C:\runROUGE-test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: You need to double the backslashes in a quoted string. Again, this would be simpler in a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you are outputting the contents of the program to the file output.out in folder sample-output, the sample-output folder does not exist.

Command Prompt will not create the folders for you, only the files. Try creating a directory first called "sample-output" (In your drive root) such that the path resolves to something like C:\sample-output and run it again.

If the same problem results, try using an absolute path such as C:\sample-output\output.out instead.

Comment: Consider tripleee's answer. That tackles the other scenario. If you did everything I said in the answer, then its probably not the problem.